# Get user properties from active directory based on user Id when user does not exist in the site using REST API

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-rest-api, user-profile

Using the following rest api resource `/_api/web/getuserbyid(1)`, I can get only the users who already have access to the site.

My problem is that I would like to get the user properties for all users from active directory,whether they have access to the site or not.

is there a way to achieve it? User profile service is not reliable.

Answer (score 0):

You can get those details using Microsoft Graph API mentioned below

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Below are some helper links based on platform where you want to use Graph API

- SPFX - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-aad-tutorial#using-aadhttpclient
- C# - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/create-requests?tabs=CS

Comment: thanks for your post, but I can't use Graph API (company policy) and no c#. It has to be Rest API only.

Comment: then as per my knowledge there is no other option because you also not able to use user profile service